# Change names of only some columns

Tags: r

I have a set of data that looks like the following:

```
V1,V2,V3,V4,lm,Q1.1,Q1.2
"ID","Set","Name","Status","lm","First Question","Second Question"
"RX0102","Default","RespondentName1",0,,1,1
"RT1832","Default","RespondentName2",0,,1,1
```

I want to take all of the columns with names that start with V and rename them using the value from the first row. I know how to get the names (`colnames(f[,c(grep("^V[0-9]*$",names(f)))])` which will return `"V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"`) and even the positions (`grep("^V[0-9]*$",names(f))` which will return `1, 2, 3, 4`) of the columns, and I know how to get the respective values from the first row (`f[1,c(grep("^V[0-9]*$", names(f)))]`). I just can't seem to assign the first row values to the names. I have tried this:

```
colnames(f[,c(grep("^V[0-9]*$",names(f)))]) <- f[1,c(grep("^V[0-9]*$", names(f)))]
```

but that does nothing. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `indices<-grep("^V[0-9]*$",names(f));colnames(f)[indices]<-as.character(unlist(x[1,indices]))`.

Comment: After changing the `x` at the end to an `f` this did the trick! I was clearly overcomplicating things. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right, it should be `f` at the end! Glad it helped anyway.

Comment: And don't forget to remove the first row: `f <- f[2:nrow(f),]`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it that way:

```
colnames(f)[grep("^V[0-9]*$",names(f))] <- f[1,c(grep("^V[0-9]*$", names(f)))]
```

Comment: That is a subtle change. That make sense now that I see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order of the columns `V` ...this should work too.

```
V1 <- c('Column Hey','1e','2e','3e','4e','5e')
V2 <- c('Column Why', 'a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e') 
X <- data.frame(V1,V2,stringsAsFactors =F)
colnames(X)[1:2] <-  as.character(X[1,1:2])
X<-X[2:nrow(X),]
```